# One script using packages that are incompatible with one version of R

Tags: overlay, rstudio, package, r-sp, spatstat

I am currently analysing movement data using the script provided by Lascelles et al (2016) in their paper "Applying global criteria to tracking data to define important areas for marine conservation". I have made some changes and additions to the script and now face the problem that the different packages needed do not work within the same version of R.

I am using the package "trip" which from what I can see works with >=3.2.5 but depends on spatstat which works with >=3.3.0. The script also uses the overlay function from the "sp" package, however this function has been deprecated, thus in order to run needs an older version of R (I have previously used version 3.0.3.

Is there a way to use multiple versions of R within the same project, or would  I have to rewrite the script to avoid using functions that do not work within the same R version?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any of the new functions/features introduced in the later versions of `trip` and `spatstat` I think you can just use the `checkpoint` package and install the versions from an earlier date. There is [a nice vignette you can have a look at](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/checkpoint/vignettes/checkpoint.html), but basically you just do something like:

```
install.packages("checkpoint")
library(checkpoint)
checkpoint("2016-01-01")
```

Comment: to specify version: `checkpoint("2016-01-01", R.version = "3.2.3")`